# Using .split and getting content

Tags: android, split

I have group of numbers divided by comma(4 numbers in it) and groups are divided by ":".

example(you see 3 groups): `2,0,6,46:3,14,22,12:0,45,65,12: .....`

I want to take this numbers;  I mean : num[3][2] -> this will choose the group which's first value is 3 and 2 means take the 2.value of group -> so in my example this will give 14

I want to get all exist values: num[0][0,1,2,3,4]; num[1][0,1,2,3,4]....

- How can I take group count?
- What kind of loop statement can I use to get every value?

I think I cant go with this code further:

```
int[][] num = new int[count of groups ][4]; // 4 is number count in a group
String[] separated = stringTime.split(".|\\:");
num[0][0]= Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);
num[0][1]= Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
num[0][2]= Integer.parseInt(separated[2]);
num[0][3]= Integer.parseInt(separated[3]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] parts = string.split(":"); // Split all by ':' into groups
int[][] num = new int[parts.length() ][4]; // Make an integer 2D array as you did

for (int i=0; i < parts.length(); i++){ // Run loop for each outer/larger group
    String[] subparts = parts[i].split(","); // Get each integer in the subgroup by splitting using ',' as delimiter 
    num[i][0]= Integer.parseInt(subparts[0]); // As you were getting integers into 2D array, do almost the same as:
    num[i][1]= Integer.parseInt(subparts[1]);
    num[i][2]= Integer.parseInt(subparts[2]);
    num[i][3]= Integer.parseInt(subparts[3]);
}
```

Hope this helps. I haven't run the code but should work.